# TypeError when using focus()

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enzyme

I have a react component having a input box. I used componentDidUpdate to set the focus to the input box. But my tests are failing with a typeError. Following is my code . Help me to pass the tests. Than you!!
This is my react component
`

```
public inputBox: any;

    componentDidUpdate = () => {
        this.inputBox.focus();
      }

    <div>
                <input

                  ref = {element => this.inputBox = element}
                  />
    </div>
```

`
When the component is updated the tests are failed. giving me this error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined

can any body can tell me whats wrong here?

Comment: would you please post more complete sample code?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the official docs:

> Note that when the referenced component is unmounted and whenever the
>   ref changes, the old ref will be called with null as an argument. This
>   prevents memory leaks in the case that the instance is stored, as in
>   the second example. Also note that when writing refs with inline
>   function expressions as in the examples here, React sees a different
>   function object each time so on every update, ref will be called with
>   null immediately before it's called with the component instance.

I believe that the ref callback gets passed `null` when the input is unmounted (that probably happens when your test ends and a different test starts).  I think you just need to test for null when you want to focus the element, like in the docs:

```
<TextInput ref={function(input) {
    if (input != null) {
        input.focus();
    }
}} />
```

Comment: That did not work. Is there any way that i can focus the input box without the componentDidUpdate when the component loads

Comment: If you just want to focus when the component loads, you should probably use `componentDidMount` instead, with a check for null.

Comment: Thanks i did it with setting a timeout.Thanks all